# Oracle PL/SQL: ORA-06502 error when assigning a string to a raw variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to load some textinformation into clob fields. I reduced the code I'm having trouble to the following snippet:

```
DECLARE
    WS_MAIN_CHUNK RAW(12001);
BEGIN
    WS_MAIN_CHUNK := 'Do';
END;
/
```

It gives me the error *ORA-06512 PL/SQL: numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error*. Why is the string 'Do' a hex value and how can I fix it -> Just assign the string to the raw variable?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle, `RAW` data type is used to store binary data and any data that is byte oriented. You cannot directly assign a string value to a variable of `RAW` datatype. If there is such a need, you can use `utl_raw` package and `cast_to_raw` function to do that:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      WS_MAIN_CHUNK raw(12001);
  3  BEGIN
  4      WS_MAIN_CHUNK :=  utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Do');
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```